# python: replace datetime.date with isoformat() in list

Tags: python, list

I want to replace the datetime objects in this list:

```
a = [
  [datetime.date(2019,1,1), 100],
  [datetime.date(2019,1,2), 187],
]
```

So I have created this function:

```
def date_to_iso(rows):

    for line in rows:
        for item in line:
            if isinstance(item, datetime.date):
                item = item.date().isoformat()
    return tempL
```

Can anybody tell me why this function is not changing the list?

Comment: use `enumerate` and indexes to change list. Or rebuild with list comprehension

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you're assigning back to `item`, you're just re-using the `item` name, but the old reference is "lost". Assign to the original list with the index instead (using the idiomatic method with `enumerate` to yield the index and the element:

```
def date_to_iso(rows):
    for line in rows:
        for i,item in enumerate(line):
            if isinstance(item, datetime.date):
                line[i] = item.date().isoformat()
```

this code uses `item` as read-only, until it's necessary to replace it in the original list.

Note that `line[i] = ...` still uses the original `line` object, that's why it works.

Another way would be to use a list comprehension to fully rebuild the data, which would require slice assignment to `rows[:]` to simulate in-place change for `rows`:

```
def date_to_iso(rows):
    rows[:] = [[item.date().isoformat() if isinstance(item, datetime.date)
                else item for item in line] for line in rows]
```